# Taking input from user in a combined way

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

im working on a question where the input is given in the below format:

```
5
7
121
123
7
121
###
4
3
3
2
5
```

Explanation of the input:

The first number is N, here in example N=5 (N>1 and N<100000). the next are N lines with different numbers ranging from 1 to 100. then comes ###. then the next number is K, here in example K=4. the next are K lines with different values ranging from 1 to 100. the '###' is used to separate N and K inputs.
my question here is how do i take the input from the user using the '###'. and later how can i differentiate between N and K. Kindly help.
please find my code below. but im not able to figure the format to write this type of input. kindly help.

```
 int n=0,N=0,k=0,y=0,K=0;
     System.out.println("Enter 'N': ");
     n=in.nextInt();
     if(n>=1 && n<=100000) {
         N=n;
     }
     int[] a1 = new int[N];
     int[] x = new int[N];
     System.out.println("Enter values of N: ");
     for (int i=0;i<a1.length;i++) {
         x[i] =  in.nextInt();
     }

     for (int i=0;i<a1.length;i++) {
         if(x[i]>=1 && x[i]<=5000) {
        a1[i] = x[i];
         }
     }

     System.out.println("Enter 'K': ");
     k=in.nextInt();
     if(k>=1 && k<=100) {
         K=k;
     }
     int[] a2 = new int[K];
     System.out.println("Enter values of K: ");
     for (int i=0;i<a2.length;i++) {
         a2[i] =  in.nextInt();
     }
```

Comment: Your question is unclear, please explain better what you want to do, and what your specific problem is.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to simply use `in.skip("###")` before reading `k` to skip the line with the separator.

Comment: actually my question is how do i take the input from the user in one single stretch along with the '###' and later separate them by N and K? as u said above... i can separate it by the `in.skip("###")`.